# "Nice shoot" or "Nice shot"?

Tags: adjectives

Someone said there's only *nice shot* and there's no such thing as *nice shoot*.

While another person told me *nice shoot* is just like *nice kick* where the *shoot*/*kick* is a verb.

p.s. why is this 'off-topic'? aren't this question about the 'word choice or usage' of an English phrase?

Comment: I have heard Nice shot as more frequent in Football matches than nice shoot.

Comment: A good dictionary will tell you that [_**kick**_](https://www.wordnik.com/words/kick) is a noun that means, "the act or an instance of kicking a ball," but that [_**shoot**_](https://www.wordnik.com/words/shoot) has no corresponding noun meaning. But this would have been a better question on [ell.se].

Comment: The Q is based on unfounded apprehension.

Comment: Why worry about the "other person"?

Comment: If you're talking about a nicely made narrow walkway through which cattle or other livestock are driven, one by one, the expression would be "Nice chute."

Comment: @Sven Yargs  OTOH, if you are a guest at an English manor for a shoot, you might compliment your host by saying "nice shoot".   Although that would be gauche.

Comment: why is this 'off-topic'? aren't this question about the 'word choice or usage' of an English phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Shoot* can be used as a noun that is similar in meaning to *shot.* Merriam-Webster's definition 2 for the noun *[shoot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shoot)* is as follows:

> **a** : an act of [shooting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shooting) (as with a bow or a firearm): (1) : [shot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shot) (2) : the firing of a missile especially by artillery
>   
> **b** (1) : a hunting trip or party (2) : the right to shoot game in a particular area or land over which it is held
>   
> **c** (1) : a shooting match · skeet *shoot* (2) : a round of shots in a shooting match
>   
> **d** : the action or an instance of shooting with a camera : a session or a series of sessions of photographing or filming · a movie *shoot*

Nevertheless, "nice shot" seems to be the established form of the expression. The Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA) contains 95 examples of "nice shot" and no examples of "nice shoot". Regardless of whether "nice shoot" in the sense of "nice shot" could be considered technically correct, I would not advise using it this way.

As wutangkillab observes, "nice shoot" is certainly possible and acceptable with other meanings; e.g. "[a nice shoot some 15 feet or 20 feet in length is procured and well ripened in the autumn](https://books.google.com/books?id=NrnonbOlMwIC&pg=PA216&lpg=PA216&dq=%22a+nice+shoot%22&source=bl&ots=jM9Z5WfPF1&sig=WEdryrIiK-HRJtrFI4B6PQ-G5io&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGgt2kn8_bAhXSMn0KHS4wDVk4FBDoAQgwMAI#v=onepage&q=%22a%20nice%20shoot%22&f=false)" (*Journal of Horticulture and Cottage Gardener,* June 18, 1861).

Comment: all answers look good, but your answer is chosen as the correct one as yours has a colored box, which stands out from the rest. (j/k, in fact yours is the most informative)

Answer (score 2):

That other person was wrong. *Nice* is an adjective, so grammatically it modifies a noun, ie *shot* (or *kick*). So you cannot say *nice shoot* with *shoot* being a verb.

If we then use the adverb *nicely* instead, that is still not enough: you would not use the present tense form in that situation. You cannot say *nicely shoot*, unless it's an imperative or an infinitive complement (*I want you to nicely shoot that ball*). It would have to be *nicely shot* (or *nicely kicked*), which is a short version of *You have nicely shot that ball*. That again rules out *shoot*.

The only situation I can think of where *nice shoot* can be used is if *shoot* is short for an event where shooting takes place, such as a hunting party. You could then use *nice shoot* analogous to *nice match* or *nice game*. But that is not the meaning you are asking about.

Comment: As far as grammar and usage are concerned "nice shoot" works and makes sense. Where's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't. Can you explain why you think it works?

Answer (score 2):

In reference to shooting a ball or a gun, *nice shoot* would not make sense, as *shoot* is the verb that corresponds to the action and *shot* is the noun. As the noun *kick* corresponds to the verb *kick*, the noun *shot* corresponds to the verb *shoot*. Therefore, *nice shoot* would be considered incorrect while *nice kick* is still considered correct.

*Nice shoot* does make sense, although not in the sense of sport; it's a noun referring to the part of a plant.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the botanical compliment.

Answer (score 1):

Shoot has meaning as a noun; act of shooting; discharge of a projectile; a shot.

So yes, you are perfectly correct.